# Increase minipage indentation inside titlepage

Tags: titles, indentation, minipage

I am having some trouble with minipages: I would like to have two minipages side-by-side, to get an output ressembling that of the linked image.

[image: output of LaTeX code]

The `supervisors` and `reading committee` columns are not correctly justified: I would like them to be such that they are under the end of the title's line (i.e. more to the right). The code to generate that output is

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\usepackage[noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage[hyphens]{xurl}



\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \hfill\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \LARGE
        \textbf{Some title}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \hfill\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace{1.5cm}

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \raggedright
        \Large{\textit{Author}:}\\
        \href{mailto:author@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Author}}}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \raggedright
        \Large{\textit{Supervisors}:} \\
        \href{mailto:prof1@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof1}}} \href{dep1Link}{(Dep1)}\\
        \href{mailto:prof2@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof2}}} \href{dep2Link}{(Dep2)}
    \end{minipage}

    \bigskip

    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \noindent
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
        \raggedright
        \Large{\textit{Reading committee}:} \\
        \href{mailto:prof1@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof1}}} \href{dep1Link}{(Dep1)}\\
        \href{mailto:prof2@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof2}}} \href{dep2Link}{(Dep2)}\\
        \href{mailto:prof3@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof3}}} \href{dep3Link}{(Dep3)}\\
        \href{mailto:prof4@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof4}}} \href{dep4Link}{(Dep4)}
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace{3.5cm}

    \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \Large
        Master's thesis carried out to obtain the degree of Master of Science in Electrical Engineering by \href{mailto:author@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Author}}}.\\
        Academic year xxxx-xxxx.
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

How could I achieve the wanted result ?

P.S. : ultimately, I will include the code into a file `titlepage.tex` to include it in a bigger document (I do not know if this information is relevant or not)

Answer (score 0):

The code can be simplified by just using two `minipages` side by side after the title.

`minipages` will put their content without indentation. To indent the supervisors and reading committee columns, you can set the indentation to any length. By using `\withof{<text>}` (`calc` package) you can set it to the same length as `\Large{\textit{Supervisors:}}`

I think it looks better to use the same indentation in both cases (see bellow).

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
\usepackage[noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage[hyphens]{xurl}

\usepackage{calc} % added <<<<<<<<<<
\newlength{\Pindent}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \LARGE
        \textbf{Some title}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
    \end{minipage}
    
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
        \raggedright
        \Large{\textit{Author:}}\par% changed <<<<<<
        \href{mailto:author@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Author}}}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}% changed <<<<<<
        \Large{\textit{Supervisors:}}% changed <<<<<<
        \setlength{\Pindent}{\widthof{\Large{\textit{Supervisors:}}}}
        {\parindent\Pindent \par
        \href{mailto:prof1@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof1}}} \href{dep1Link}{(Dep1)}\par
        \href{mailto:prof2@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof2}}} \href{dep2Link}{(Dep2)}}\par
        \medskip
        \Large{\textit{Reading committee:}}
        \setlength{\Pindent}{\widthof{\Large{\textit{Reading committee:}}}} % try this
        {\parindent\Pindent \par    
        \href{mailto:prof1@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof1}}} \href{dep1Link}{(Dep1)}\par
        \href{mailto:prof2@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof2}}} \href{dep2Link}{(Dep2)}\par
        \href{mailto:prof3@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof3}}} \href{dep3Link}{(Dep3)}\par
        \href{mailto:prof4@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof4}}} \href{dep4Link}{(Dep4)}
        }
    \end{minipage}  
    
    \vspace{3.5cm}
    
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \Large
        Master's thesis carried out to obtain the degree of Master of Science in Electrical Engineering by \href{mailto:author@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Author}}}.\\
        Academic year xxxx-xxxx.
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Un-commenting the line

```
\setlength{\Pindent}{\widthof{\Large{\textit{Reading committee:}}}}
```

you will get

[image: b]

Perhaps a better alternative for a title page would be

[image: c]

using

```
    \setlength{\Pindent}{\widthof{\Large{\textit{Supervisors:}}}}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \parindent\Pindent 
        \href{mailto:author@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Author}}}
    \end{minipage}
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}% changed <<<<<<
        \Large{\textit{Supervisors:}}% changed <<<<<<       
        {\parindent\Pindent \par
        \href{mailto:prof1@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof1}}} \href{dep1Link}{(Dep1)}\par
        \href{mailto:prof2@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof2}}} \href{dep2Link}{(Dep2)}}\par
        \medskip
        \Large{\textit{Reading committee:}}
        {\parindent\Pindent \par    
        \href{mailto:prof1@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof1}}} \href{dep1Link}{(Dep1)}\par
        \href{mailto:prof2@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof2}}} \href{dep2Link}{(Dep2)}\par
        \href{mailto:prof3@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof3}}} \href{dep3Link}{(Dep3)}\par
        \href{mailto:prof4@address.com}{\large{\textsc{Prof4}}} \href{dep4Link}{(Dep4)}
        }
    \end{minipage}
```

Comment: Hi @simon, thank you for your answer, it offers nice ways to format the page, plus you give directly the output, which is really nice :)